# Deep clone array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object that maintains an internal array of objects. I have a method that returns the array but I need to prevent external manipulation of the array and the objects inside it.

Trying `slice` to copy the array but I've noticed that the objects inside are still *references* to the originals while the array itself is new. I've never noticed this before, but I've confirmed it:

```
function test(){

    // I want this to be safe from outside influence
    var a = [{
        val: 1   
    },{
        val: 2   
    }];

    return {
        all: function(){
            return a.slice();
        }
    }
}

var instance = test();
var copy = instance.all();

// This affects both "copy" and the original
copy[0].val = 'wrong';

// This clears "copy" but doesn't affect the original
copy = [];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dczz7sL4/1/

I need to have a truly new copy so an outsider can't modify the array without using the API methods I've designed. I assume all I can do iterate the array and use `$.extend` (or similar methods from other libs) to clone the objects individually - is there any easier/native alternative?

Comment: Interesting performance test: http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/6...

Comment: None of the comments/answers are addressing the fact that these are objects in array. I don't want to individually clone every object and build a new array, but it seems that all I can do.

Comment: The first nor the second question on the duplicate answer referenced an array of objects?...

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation of a deep copy is

```
function clone(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Note that this won't work if you have cyclical references in your object, or if you have functions.

You can also use `jQuery.extend` passing true as the first argument for a deep copy

```js
var a =[{a:1}]
var b = $.extend(true, [], a);
b[0].a = 0;
$('#first').html(JSON.stringify(a));
$('#second').html(JSON.stringify(b));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

First Array: <span id='first'></span> <br />
Clonde Array: <span id='second'></span>
```

Comment: Note that there is also an issue with date conversion. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object#comment-39444922).